# Web Developer: Conselho de evolução: próximo passo?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, wordpress

Bom dia a todos,

Preciso do vosso conselho e da vossa experiência para evoluir na carreira.
Sou Web Developer há 2/3 anos. Sempre trabalhei a fazer tudo de raiz, trabalho com HTML, Javascript, CSS, PHP, MySql. Faço tudo em Mysql Workbench e no Brackets. Mas sinto que não sei o suficiente ainda. Há sensivelmente 1 ano vim a trabalhar com Wordpress, penso que CSM seja muito importante nos tempos que correm. O problema é no que diz respeito a o que escolher para evoluir! Por exemplo, sei que no Javascript, temos frameworks Angular etc. Qual o que devo escolher? é melhor usar framework? o mesmo se dá com o PHP, existe Laravel, Cakephp etc. sinto que são ferramentas importantes, mas qual escolher e porquê? e por exemplo ruby on rails, python? O meu problema é haver tanta opção e conteúdo que não sei para onde seguir caminho. Sinto que html, javascript, css, mysql e php apenas não me são suficientes para aceitar qualquer proposta da web sinto que o meu conhecimento é limitado relativamente ao que vejo na net.
Se me pudessem orientar e aconselhar o melhor caminho agradecia.

Cumprimentos a todos.

Comment: Esse tipo de pergunta você de fazer no [chat do site](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha)

Comment: Obrigado @rray ♦, mas não consigo falar no chat devido a falta de repputation, se me pudesse ajudar agradecia. Não sei se a pergunta é ridicula, mas a verdade é que me sinto perdido no meio de tanta coisa.
Cumps

Comment: Também me sentia, ou me sinto da mesma maneira, sei como é. Sobre "para aceitar qualquer proposta da web" eu recomendo aprender outras linguagens que podem ser utilizadas na web, eu mesmo também conhecia apenas as linguagens que você citou (Não sou profissional, apenas opinião), como por exemplo, comecei a aprender C# e vi que ele me oferece tantos recursos bacanas que não eu não tinha em PHP, apesar do PHP ser mais fácil de desenvolver. Existem muitas linguagens que também podem ser utilizadas pra Web, mas também não abandone o PHP.

Comment: @ViníciusLima obrigado pela dica. É complicado focar num caminho só, quando há tanta coisa diferente. Sei que pode parecer absurdo isto, mas sinto-me um bocado sem saber para onde virar.  Tanto em frameworks como em linguagens

Comment: @leugim Me sinto da mesma maneira kkkkk, até porque o contato mais próximo que tive com programadores é aqui no Stack, então nunca tive uma conversa com alguém, ou seja meio que tenho apenas "minha ideia de como as coisas funcionam" infelizmente...  :'(

Comment: @ViníciusLima esperemos que alguém com experiência na matéria nos oriente :)